# how to set php session with jquery/ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, session

I would like to set php session with ajax.
there is my function to set session in session.php.

```
public static function set($key, $value) {  
    $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
}
```

and I have confirm javascript alert and if I click on yes, i want to set session.
How can I set session simply?

**EDIT** 16.4.2012 15:31 GMT:+1

David: thanks for an answer, it looks clearly. I tried it, but doesn´t do anything at my pc. So I have: a.php

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<p>I would like to say: </p>
<script>
    $("p").append("<strong>Hello</strong>"); //check jquery is working 
    $.get('a.php', function(data) {
        // do something on success?
    });
</script>
```

b.php (in same folder)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('aaa');
</script>
<?php
echo "print by b.php";
?>
```

and I run a.php in browser

Comment: have you written session_start before you assign value to the $_SESSION ?

Comment: @user1336101: When you say things like "run in browser" and "doesn't do anything at my PC" my first thought is that maybe you don't have a PHP-enabled web server?  What local web server are you using, and does PHP work on that web server at all?

Comment: Also, if PHP _is_ working, can you debug this request in something like Firebug?  That way you can see what the response is.  (Because it doesn't look like it's going to give any indication in the UI that there was a response, since you're not doing anything on success in the AJAX call.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a simple PHP page which does nothing more than set the value (using the code you already have), and then have jQuery call that page:

```
$.get('setsessionvalue.php', function(data) {
  // do something on success?
});
```

If you want to expand it, you can make the call more general by passing values on the query string:

```
$.get('setsessionvalue.php?key=someKey&value=someValue', function(data) {
  // do something on success?
});
```

Then you'd pull those query string values from the `$_GET` collection on the server just like any other page.

From the server-side code's perspective, it's not different than any other page.  You just don't need to render a UI (and can render data if you want, probably easiest in JSON format).  The JavaScript code is just calling that page like any other page.

It's worth noting, of course, that a user can call this page manually if they want to.  So don't use this as any kind of "security" for session values.  If a user goes to the URL:

```
setsessionvalue.php?key=someKey&value=someValue
```

then they would be able to set their session values manually.  Even overriding the values you've already set (which they can see in the JavaScript code).  I wouldn't be particularly comfortable exposing the structure of session values (especially their keys) to client-side code like that.  It seems like a short distance away from having some security holes in your site.